# Trying to install LAMP on Centos?

Tags: centos, lamp, centos6

Hey guys I'm running Centos 6.2 minimal, and I am trying to install LAMP for my server and following [this tutorial](http://www.scribd.com/doc/67745526/Step-By-Step-Install-Guide-CentOS-6-Server-Administration-and-Maintenance).

It installed flawlessly however when I try to configure the services to start automatically, its cool with

```
/sbin/chkconfig httpd on
```

but when I try

```
/sbin/chkconfig --add mysqld
```

it says:

> error reading information on service mysqld: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

is mysqld installed? try yum install mysql-server or some such. it might also not be named mysqld but mysql see /etc/init.d/ directory for the scripts.

Comment: Just tried yum install mysql-server, couldn't get all the packages to install but I don't think its as big of a deal. I chekced out /etc/init.d/ and didn't see anything along the lines of mysql :/

Comment: did you see the other service scripts there along the lines of  "ntpd" "xinetd" etc.? if so, that means you don't have the mysql server installed and you need to work on installing it. IIRC mysql-server is the critical package.

Answer (score 0):

System cannot find mysqld in /etc/init.d

Try: locate mysqld

Normally it will be /u/sbin or /u/bin folder (depends on Operating system and default settings).

copy mysqld (if you find it) to /etc/init.d folder, check the file permission.

Then try chkconfig --add mysqld again.

Post your result of the command above if you still cannot get it going.